# anti cache code to jquery getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was asked this in an interview :

> What is the proper syntax to add an anti-cache code to all jQuery
>   getJson calls throughout a given project (without adding it to each
>   getJson call). He asked me one liner code for this?

I am not sure how we can do this in one line?

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.ajaxSetup(options)` to set default options that affect all subsequent AJAX calls, so you can do something like:

`$.ajaxSetup({'cache': false});`

[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)